# How do I check for login or other status before launching a route in Angular with routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Let's say I have 4 routes - 2 require the user to be logged in, 2 do not. My app init looks like:

```
        $routeProvider.when('/open1',{templateUrl:'/open1.html',controller:'Open1'});
        $routeProvider.when('/open2',{templateUrl:'/open2.html',controller:'Open2'});
        $routeProvider.when('/secure1',{templateUrl:'/secure1.html',controller:'Secure1'});
        $routeProvider.when('/secure2',{templateUrl:'/secure2.html',controller:'Secure2'});
```

Routes `/open1` and `/open2` are open to all, while routes `/secure1` and `/secure2` require the user to be logged in and, if not, take some action, e.g. redirect to login or launch a warning. I can determine the user's state by using my `Auth` service and calling, e.g., `Auth.isLogin()`. So the result would be:

- going to `/open1` and `/open2` always go to the template and controller declared above
- if `Auth.isLogin()` returns true, `/secure1` and `/secure2` go to the above-declared template and controller
- if `Auth.isLogin()` returns false, `/secure1` and `/secure2` take some other action, e.g. `$location.path('/login')`

I *could* put logic in the `Secure1` and `Secure2` controllers that checks, but that is repetitive and mixes up responsibilities, makes them harder to test, etc.

Is there a way that I can use the `$routeProvider` to declare, "check this route and this route and if not, redirect"? I was thinking of using `resolve` somehow, but not quite sure how to work it in (docs on `resolve` are not very clear, and few helpful examples).

EDIT:

based on the answers below, it appears there are three philosophies for doing this:

- Using `resolve` to check logged in and fail the promise, and then catching the `$routeChangeError` event to redirect http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/
- Using just `$routeChangeStart` event to check logged in and redirect http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/
- Using just resolve to check logged in and redirect http://midgetontoes.com/blog/2014/08/31/angularjs-check-user-login

The 2nd option is what the two answerers have suggested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As in my comments above, there are 3 different paths (plus the ability to use a directive if you want to control it from within html templates). I ended up following

https://midgetontoes.com/angularjs-check-user-login/

which essentially is as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when('/secure', {
    templateUrl: '/secure.html', 
    controller: 'Secure',
    resolve:{
        loggedIn:onlyLoggedIn
    }
 });
```

And then `onlyLoggedIn`:

```
var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q,Auth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (Auth.isLogin()) {
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        deferred.reject();
        $location.url('/login');
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Simple, works like a charm. If I ever need a directive, I will pull this piece into a service.

Comment: Can you please mention where to put var onlyLoggedIn, like in which scope? I am very new to it. @deitch

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha I just declare it as a local variable function in my app.js and then reference it in my `$routeProvider`. But it can be anywhere you want, since you always can `require()` or otherwise include it.

Comment: Your url is dead

Comment: url isn't dead anymore, I got it back :)

Comment: it's dead again, so let's take a wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160512034000/https://midgetontoes.com/angularjs-check-user-login/

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app) deals with user authentication in AngularJS using directives.

The $route service emits $routeChangeStart before a route change.

If you don't use directives, you can catch that event by calling app.run (you can place it after the code where you define the routes [app.config]). For example:

For full disclosure I use ui.router and this is an adapted code from [$stateChangeStart](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events) I use in my app

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/open1',{templateUrl:'/open1.html',controller:'Open1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/open2',{templateUrl:'/open2.html',controller:'Open2'});
    $routeProvider.when('/secure1',{templateUrl:'/secure1.html',controller:'Secure1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/secure2',{templateUrl:'/secure2.html',controller:'Secure2'});
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currRoute, prevRoute){
        var logged = Auth.isLogin();

        //check if the user is going to the login page
        // i use ui.route so not exactly sure about this one but you get the picture
        var appTo = currRoute.path.indexOf('/secure') !== -1;

        if(appTo && !logged) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: So I can use `$routeChangeStart` event to capture and prevent the continuation? I would still need to know the paths, and would prefer to do it in the `$routeProvider.when()` if I can, but this would work. This is similar to @JasonvanderZeeuw answer below. I will read the blog post, thank you

Comment: @deitch I would recommend [AngularUI router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/) because it uses states instead of urls. For example, state could be _secure.report_ or _secure.list_ while the url would be _/report_ or _/list_, then you would only check if the state contains _secure_ in the name, without knowing the exact links

Comment: The blog is interesting. Rather than doing it on the route, he suggests setting a directive on the template. Not sure I like that approach, I think I prefer it at the route (or state) level, but the idea might work. I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did it this way:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',["ui-bootstrap"]);
```

And then listen for a locationchange in the app (this will also trigger onEnter of a page)

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore) {
 $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    //Here you can check whatever you want (servercall, cookie...)
 });
}
```

I Hope this helps!

Comment: It is not a bad plan, but then I need to add logic per route in the event handler, and how would I stop a particular route from running?

Comment: I added 'throw "stop execution";' which will stop all javascript activity. And did a redirect to a loginpage. In the function I check whether $location.path == "/signin";

Comment: I guess it would work. Is there nothing inside the `$routeProvider` that can help?

Comment: No there's nothing in the $routeprovider for authentication, you could always take a look at an external module like https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Comment: I ended up following http://midgetontoes.com/blog/2014/08/31/angularjs-check-user-login using resolve. It was the simplest.

Comment: I used this code to run google analytics for each page view, because it runs everytime the route changed and I could pass up some key data. I didn't need the $cookieStore though.